# fabric postgresql create database

Tags: postgresql, fabric

What would be equivalent of this in postgresql

```
run('echo "CREATE DATABASE %s;"|mysql --batch --user=%s --password=%s --host=%s' % (dataname, env.mysqluser, env.mysqlpassword, env.mysqlhost), pty=True)
```

The above works fine for creating mysql database, but how would you create one in postgresql without getting stuck at password prompt.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I do it:-

```
run('psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE {0} WITH PASSWORD \'{1}\' NOSUPERUSER CREATEDB NOCREATEROLE LOGIN;"'.format(env.psql_user, env.psql_password))
run('psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE {0} WITH OWNER={1} TEMPLATE=template0 ENCODING=\'utf-8\';"'.format(env.psql_db, env.psql_user))
```

Comment: Would you use "WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD" instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- [set PGPASSWORD](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-envars.html)
- [use .pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html)
- [change pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Choose whatever suits you best. I would probably go with .pgpass.

Answer (score 0):

psql reads [~/.pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

You can also use non-password-based authentication methods. Consult [PostgreSQL's documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/client-authentication.html) for more.